# Create an item if a value from my SQL data doesn't match any data in my SharePoint list

Tags: office365, power-automate

The flow is:

- Trigger - start flow when "Item is created" (SQL database)
  check specific value from the SQL data with the data in my SharePoint list
- IF that value does not exist in my SharePoint list -> then "True" -> "Create Item" (SharePoint)
  False do nothing

I can get the flow to work with the trigger and to create items in the SP list with the data coming from SQL. But if the flow runs a again because a new item was created, then it creates all the items again from the database.
That's when I get duplicates, so the issue started when I wanted to filter the data and only create new items from the database.

My entire flow

[image]

My Condition

[image]

The expression used is `length(body('Get_items')?['value']) is equeal to 0`

I have tried different combinations

to start with I just tried to do the condition directly on the values they're called "blanketnummer"(SQL) and "Blanketnummer"(Sharepoint List)

In an out "Apply to each" control action

i have also tried with to switch "Get items" out with "Get rows" instead
and then use the expression: `length(body('Get_rows')?['value'])`

but it won't even save it.

Comment: from what you write, it is unclear if you have one or two problems. First, you say the flow seems to fire twice on the same SQL row. Also, you say the flow condition cannot detect if the item already exists in SP. Can you confirm if there's any difference between the data triggering the flow runs? If so, you need a trigger condition. You may also have to modify how you search data in SP, since the 'body' array in your condition always seems to evaluate empty.

Comment: Sorry maybe that was s little unclear, what meant was that I can get the flow to work with the trigger and to create items in the SP list with the data coming from SQL. But if the flow runs a again because a new item was created then it creates all the items again from the database, that's when I get duplicates in my SP list. I will update my post with a better explanation.

Comment: OK. Can you also confirm that the items previously created in SP are correctly found by the 'Get items' action (i.e. the array is not empty)?

Comment: Sorry I'm on phone and when I want to do new line it posts my comment, so o have edited my comment with the rest of the information.

Comment: what is the array the 'Apply to each' is iterating over?

Comment: I think it is iteration over the body/value of SP get items